# Image->JSON->.Net Image

Tags: javascript, c#, json, knockout.js

I am trying to learn Knockout and trying to create a photo uploader. I have successfully stored some images in an Array. Now I want to post back. In my knockout code (Javascript), I do this:

I have an image 'class' in Javascript:

```
// The image object that wukk be posted back.
function Image(_Image, _Description, _Filesize, _Filetype) {
    var self = this;
    self.Image =_Image;
    self.Description = _Description;
    self.Filesize = _Filesize;
    self.Filetype = _Filetype;

    self.DisplaySize = ko.computed(function () {
        SizeToText(self.Filesize);
    });
}
```

I have an array of these in a property called 'images'.

When I click the save button, I try to simply stringify the array of images into 'object'.

```
  var object = JSON.stringify({
                images: self.images(),
            });
```

I then post my object back to my .net WebAPI controller.

```
    var uri = "/api/Photo/Upload";
    $.post({ url: uri, contentType: "application/json" }, object)
    .done(function (data) {
        self.images.removeAll();
    });
```

My method gets called, and I can see in the data it receives, all the image data, descriptions etc.

The method is defined as:

```
public int Upload(UIImageUploadList data)
```

And a UIImageUploadList is a class that holds a list of images:

```
public class UIImageUploadList
{
    public List<UIImageUpload> Images { get; set; }
}
```

and UIImageUpload is:

```
 public class UIImageUpload
    {

        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        public int FileSize { get; set; }

    }
```

So, I try and parse the data from the 'data' field, so that I can pass it to my service/logic/data layer.

```
foreach(var p in data.Images)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var routes_list =
                       json_serializer.DeserializeObject(p.Image);


                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(p.Image);

                Image image;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                }

                photos.Add(new Photo
                {
                    Description = p.Description,
                    PhotoData = image
                });
            }
```

But it's in Base64, I think. (JSON.Stringify did that I believe).

The image property starts with this:

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAJY
```

and ends with:

```
AElFTkSuQmCC"
```

I know if it's  JPG or a BMP etc.

In .Net, I try to change this into an Image type, to pass to my DB.

But it fails "DeserializeObject" saying that 'data is not a primitive JSON type'.

How should I be converting to an image that will finally be stored in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling `Convert.FromBase64String`, you will need to split the string containing the encoded image data. First, strip of the `data:`, then you get the MIME type for the image (`image/png`), then the encoding (`base64`) and only the remainder of the string (after the comma) can be passed into the conversion function. I don't have much experience with C# but from there on the `FromStream` function should be smart enough to deal with the decoded data.